# How can I create a tooltip like the ones in Google+?

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

[image]

I am trying to create functionality like Google+ in which if the user resizes the window, the menu items on the left get hidden and when user hovers the more link the hidden menu items start to show in a tooltip as I show in the image above.

I am halfway done. I captured the window resize event and successfully appended the hidden list item (li) in a div. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/home_active.png"> <em>Home</em></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/msg_active.png"> <em>Messages</em></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/reports_active.png"> <em>Reports</em></a></li>
      <li style="display: none;"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/mng_active.png"> <em>Manager</em></a></li>
      <li style="display: none;"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/shop_active.png"> <em>Shop</em></a> </li>
      <li class="mymore" style="display: block;"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/more_active.png"> <em>More</em></a> 
        <div id="mytooltip" style=""><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/mng_active.png"> <em>Manager</em></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../images/icons/shop_active.png"> <em>Shop</em></a> </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
```

Carefully look the code. I appended the hidden li (check li having style="diplay:none") in the div id="mytooltip". But now on hover on the li (having class = mymore) I want to show the div id="mytooltip" as tooltip, as shown in image. And I also need to hide this tooltip if the user is not hovering the tooltip. How can I do this?

Comment: Whatever your approach, MVC is going to make life a lot easier.

Comment: @Madbreaks What does MVC have to do with this?

Comment: @Madbreaks which MVC?

Comment: @user2019515 You seem to know what MVC is - using MVC as an approach to a reasonably complex data/view problem like this is (quote) *going to make life a lot easier*.  Without, I guarantee the solution will be needlessly complex and, at the very least, difficult to support.

Comment: @AshishSingh I think you mean *which implementation*.  An example would be `backbone.js`.  But you don't need to use someone else's solution, I'm merely suggesting leveraging MVC design principles as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the "mymore" link add a class to the tooltip which would enable it's visibility.

Using jquery, you can use the hover event. The example below adds an "active" class to the tooltip. This active class simply sets its display to block.

```
$(".mymore").hover(function () {
    $("#mytooltip").addClass("active"); //hover over
}, function () {
    $("#mytooltip").removeClass("active"); //hover out
});
```

EDIT:
You probably don't want the tooltip to close if the user hovers over the actual tooltip. You can get around this by using a timer. For example, if the user mouses out of the "mymore" button, we can try to close the button in .5 seconds. If the user hovers over the actual tooltip before that timer is done, we can simply clear the timer.

```
ToolTip = {
    interval: null,
    timer: 600,
    open: function () {
        clearTimeout(ToolTip.interval);
        $("#mytooltip").addClass("active");
    },
    close: function () {
        ToolTip.interval = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#mytooltip").removeClass("active");
        }, ToolTip.timer) //hover out
    }
}

$(".mymore, #mytooltip").hover(function () {
    ToolTip.open() //hover over
}, function () {
    ToolTip.close() //hover out
});
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J9WB7/